# New counter that counts total number of parts

Tags: counters, parts

I want to create a counter that counts the total number of `\part`s. I have the `totcount` package installed, and I have read the package documentation, without being able to even remotely create something that works even a little bit (so I don't have an MWE).

It seems no one else has the same problem as me, because I can't find any relatable question which has a solution that can be applied to my problem.

I'm using the online-based LaTeX solution called Overleaf, but my experience tells me that everything is working the same way as the 'offline' solutions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are all `\part`s of your document numbered, or are there unnumbered parts as well (presumably created by `\part*`)?

Comment: All of them are numbered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/totcount/totcount.pdf) of the `totcount` package, use `\regcount` to register a counter and `\total` to retrieve the count:

```
\regtotcounter{part}
\newcommand*{\partcount}{\total{part}}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{part}
\newcommand*{\partcount}{\total{part}}

\begin{document}

This document has \partcount{} parts.

\part{A}

\part{B}

\part{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need to run LaTeX **twice** to get the count.

---

You can use the `fmtcount` package ([documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.pdf)) if you want the number to be spelled out in English (three instead of 3).  The `\numberstringnum` only accepts nonnegative values, so the first run needs special treatment (where the count is -1): (using the `etoolbox` package)

```
\newcommand*{\partcount}{%
  \ifnumcomp{\totvalue{part}}{<}{0}{???}{\numberstringnum{\totvalue{part}}}%
}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage{totcount}

\regtotcounter{part}
\newcommand*{\partcount}{%
  \ifnumcomp{\totvalue{part}}{<}{0}{???}{\numberstringnum{\totvalue{part}}}%
}

\begin{document}

This document has \partcount{} parts.

\part{A}

\part{B}

\part{C}

\end{document}
```

First run:

[image]

Second run:

[image]

The package offers more styles, such as Three, THREE, third, 3rd, 3<sup>rd</sup>, etc.  See the documentation for the corresponding commands.

Comment: This works as intended, but, because all numbers below 10 are required to be spelled out (a requirement from my university), is it then possible to make it spell out the number ("three" in this case)?

Comment: @L.Nielsen Does your university really want all single digit numbers to be spelled out? What about page numbers, sectional division numbers, float numbers, equation numbers, etc.? What is your university? --- GOM

Comment: @L.Nielsen I've updated the answer to address that.

Comment: @PeterWilson Unfortunately yes. I'm a student on Aalborg University in Denmark. Solely numbers in-line: "I have 10 fingers but only two hands", page numbers, figure numbers, chapters, sections, and so on aren't included in the requirement.